# Error while loading libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0

Tags: node.js, linux, shared-libraries, puppeteer, shared-hosting

I have created a NodeJS app which is using Puppeteer.
Locally (Windows) it is working totally fine, but when I wanted to deploy the app on a shared hosting platform (Linux Server), I got the following error:

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!\n/var/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-818858/chrome-linux/chrome: **error while loading shared libraries: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0**: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: [https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md\n"](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md%5Cn%22)

The only solution I found was to install the missing libatk-bridge dependency with

`sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev`

but the problem is, I **don't have the rights** to do so on the shared hosting platform.

Is there any workaround to solve the issue? Or is there a way to embed the library as a static library instead of a shared library?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: @Chandrakanth Stucked in the same problem, did you find the solution?

Comment: I'm also stucked in that problem.. If someone find a workaround, could be great to share !

Comment: I am leaving this link here because I spent way too much time with this error. This finally helped me solve the problem:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1598